# python peewee query, with column name as variable

Tags: python, peewee

Peewee query is as following:

```
q = AccountTab.get(AccountTab.id == 12345)
print(q.name)
```

What if `name` here is stored in a variable, say `user_name`. Is there something like this?

```
q = AccountTab.get(AccountTab.id == 12345)
print(q.#{user_name})
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) will work:

```
user_name = 'name'
print(getattr(q, user_name))
```